# Unity 2D Raycast Detecting Object Problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

> [image: Blockquote]

It detects the beam even if it passes over the object. I want it to detect when it's right on the object.

```
void RaycastSystem()
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    Vector2 worldMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

    Vector2 rayDirection = worldMousePosition - (Vector2)transform.position;

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, rayDirection, rayDirection.magnitude, mask);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, rayDirection, Color.red);
    //Debug.Log(worldMousePosition.x + " | " + worldMousePosition.y);

    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject);
    }
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: you mean you need it to be at the end of the ray not part way down it? surely the simplest answer then is not a ray but just to check its the right distance?

Comment: i didn't understand what you said 

Comment: you are not clear in your question - how is the item supposed to be "right on the object" if a  ray goes through it, it is "right on the object" if the ray has to end where the object is (as per my question) its less about the ray more about how far...

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I couldn't explain my problem properly. Even if the ray passes through the object, it continues to detect the object. I want it to detect only when the ray is right on top of the object, so I'm having an issue with the detection location of the ray. I hope this explanation is clear.

Comment: As I said so do you want it only when the end of the ray is within the object?

Comment: yes sir i want that.

Comment: (not male) but, then as I said if you need to check then it would be simpler to test its a certain distance.  You have choices so you can use a ray cast to determine its got "line of sight" but a ray will only answer if it found either any object or objects of given layers between it and the end of its ray, it wont only look at the end.  So, you either then check its within a given range of distance (eg size of object looked for as the range to add) or just check that the object is within that range and line of sight is not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your latest comments correctly you actually want to have two checks

- Is the user hovering an object with the mouse
- Can the same object be hit by the raycast from the player object

So you would combine both

```
void RaycastSystem()
{
    Vectror2 worldMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    // first check if hitting an object with the mouse
    var mouseHit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(worldMousePosition);
    if(mouseHit != null)
    {
        var rayDirection = worldMousePosition - (Vector2)transform.position;

        // then check via raycast
        var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, rayDirection, rayDirection.magnitude, mask);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            if(hit.collider == mouseHit)
            {
                Debug.Log("HIT {hit.collider.name}!");
                // do something with hit
            }
            // else some other object is in between
        }
        // else not hitting anything with the ray (e.g. too far away)
    }
    // else not hitting anything with the mouse
}
```

Can of course invert the order and first do the raycast and then in the inner block do the mouse check - according to your needs / performance checks.

Comment: I want it to detect when my mouse hovers over the object. If my mouse isn't over the object, I want it to not detect it.

Comment: @MuhammedEren so you want to check both: If the mouse hits the target + if the player raycast hits it as well?

Comment: yes sir you're right.

Comment: i love you bro. you're a hero. thank you ❤

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you only want it to detect the object when the cursor is directly on it and not when there's a line through the object, then you're very close. The issue is what you are testing is if there is any colliders between the transform and the mouse cursor. Instead of casting a Ray from the character transform, you want to raycast from the 'Screen'. Unity has a built in way of doing this thankfully.

Try something like this

```
void RaycastSystem()
    {
        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
    
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, mask))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject);
        }
        
    }
```

Essentially what this approach is doing is casting the ray direction from the mouse point on the screen -into- the screen.

Comment: not working bro but thanks.